# Scroll to top when adding new items

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a usecase where I would like a `LazyColumn` to scroll to the top if a new item is added to the start of the list - but only if the list was scrolled to top before. I'm currently using keys for bookkeeping the scroll position automatically, which is great for all other cases than when the scroll state is at the top of the list.

This is similar to the actual logic I have in the app (in my case there is however no button, `showFirstItem` is a parameter to the composable function, controlled by some other logic):

```
var showFirstItem by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
Column {
    Button(onClick = { showFirstItem = !showFirstItem }) {
        Text("${if (showFirstItem) "Hide" else "Show"} first item")
    }

    LazyColumn {
        if (showFirstItem) {
            item(key = "first") {
                Text("First item")
            }
        }

        items(count = 100,
            key = { index ->
                "item-$index"
            }
        ) { index ->
            Text("Item $index")
        }
    }
}
```

As an example, I would expect "First item" to be visible if I scroll to top, hide the item and them show it again. Or hide the item, scroll to top and then show it again.

I think the solution could be something with `LaunchedEffect`, but I'm not sure at all.

Answer (score 1):

In your item adding logic,

```
scrollState.animateScrollToItem(0)
//Add an optional delay here
showFirst = ... //Handle here whatever you want
```

Here, `scrollState` is to be passed in the LazyColumn

`val scrollState = rememberScrollState() LazyColumn(state = scrollState) { ... }`

Comment: But how to do that only when a new item is added and we are at the top?

Comment: If u already are at the top, it will have no effect

Comment: What else do you want?

Comment: Are you trying to do this only when you are at the top? That doesn't make sense. You want to go to the top when you are already there?

Comment: When adding a new item there's two cases: 1) The user was scrolled to the top of the list before adding the new item. When adding the new item (to the start/top) the scroll position isn't at the top anymore (it's at the second item) and in that exact case I would like to scroll to the top. 2) The user was scrolled to e.g. middle of the list, at that point I don't want any automatic scroll to happen when new item is added (the scroll position should stay the same). And in general we only want to change the scroll position programatically when a new item is added.

Answer (score 1):

If a new item has been added and user is at top, the new item would not appear unless the list is scrolled to the top. I have tried this:

```
if (lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex <= 1) {
            //scroll to top to ensure latest added book gets visible
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = key) {
                lazyListState.scrollToItem(0)
            }
        }
LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = lazyListState
        ) {...
```

And it seems to work. But it breaks the pull to refresh component that I am using. So not sure how to solve that. I am still trying to force myself to like Compose. Hopefully that day will come =)

Comment: To make it work every time i had to usde SifeEffect instead of LauchedEffect..

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
@Composable
private fun ListOfItems(
    items: List<Item>,
) {
    val state = rememberLazyListState()

    LaunchedEffect(items) {
        snapshotFlow { state.firstVisibleItemIndex }
            .collect {
                // Scroll to the top if a new item is added.
                // (But only if user is scrolled to the top already.)
                if (it <= 1) {
                    state.scrollToItem(0)
                }
            }
    }

    LazyColumn(
        state = state,
    ) {
       // contents
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the top of the list on a LazyColumn like this:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
...
Button(onClick = {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        // 0 is the first item index
        scrollState.animateScrollToItem(0)
    }
}) {
    Text("Scroll to the top")
}
```

So call `scrollState.animateScrollToItem(0)` where ever you need from a coroutine, e.g. after adding a new item.

Comment: But how to do that only when a new item is added and we are at the top? I don't have a button I can hook up to (as explained in the original question).

Comment: You can launch the coroutine anywhere without any button click, whenever you need to scroll to the top of the list, e.g.
`
    if (showFirstItem) {
            item(key = "first") {
                Text("First item")
            }

            coroutineScope.launch {
                    scrollState.animateScrollToItem(0)
            }
    }
`

It is not any problem to scroll to the top, even if you are already on the top of the list.

If it does not help, please share your full code for more understanding.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah didn't think about you could do it in most places - thanks! But I still only want to do that if the list was at top - and only do it once per added item. Could be done with `scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex`, but I need to make sure it's checked at the correct time.

Comment: The scrolling will happen inside a coroutine on a separate thread, which will not block the main thread (UI thread). So you can scroll as many times as you want, without any performance issue, if you can't find a better solution.

Comment: My question isn't because of performance, it's because I don't want it to scroll at a later point (unless yet another has been added). If I just check `scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 1` after inserting the new value (and how would I do that?), it would also happen next time you scroll to index 1 and thus it wouldn't be possible to scroll away from index 0.